# Rspec testing No Route Matches ActionController::UrlGenerationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to wrap my head about Rspec and Controller tests, more specifically a JSON request.  In this case, I'm trying to hit the `v1_devices_path` route:

> routes.rb

```
v1_device_scans POST   /v1/devices/:device_serial_number/scans(.:format) v1/scans#create
v1_device       GET    /v1/devices/:serial_number(.:format)              v1/devices#show
                PATCH  /v1/devices/:serial_number(.:format)              v1/devices#update
                PUT    /v1/devices/:serial_number(.:format)              v1/devices#update
```

And my controller:

> controllers/v1/devices_controller.rb

```
class V1::DevicesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_device, only: [:show, :update]
  respond_to :json

  def show
    @device = Device.find_by(serial_number: params[:serial_number])
    render :json => @device.as_json
  end

  def update
    if @device.update(device_params)
      render json: @device, status: :ok, location: @device
    else
      render json: @device.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private

  def set_device
    @device = Device.find_by!(serial_number: params[:serial_number])
  end

  def device_params
    params.require(:device).permit(
      :serial_number,
      :name,
      :diagnostic_checkin_status,
      :diagnostic_dns,
      :diagnostic_ping,
      :assigned_internal_ip,
      :assigned_external_ip,
      :assigned_gateway_ip,
      :version,
      :timezone,
      :task_id,
      :scan_status,
      :scan_progress
    )
  end

end
```

As of right now my test is super simple... just want to make sure I get some results back:

> spec/controllers/v1/devices_controller_spec.rb

require 'rails_helper'

```
RSpec.describe V1::DevicesController, type: :controller do

  it "shows device info" do
    device = FactoryGirl.create(:device)
    get v1_device_path(device.serial_number), :format => :json
    expect(response.status).to be(200)
  end
end
```

After some tweaking, I've gotten to the point where it looks like my url is being created correctly, but I'm still getting the `no route matches` error:

```
  1) V1::DevicesController shows device info
     Failure/Error: get v1_device_path(device.serial_number), :format => :json

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"/v1/devices/41442305171c430ab253ba1ad95c5c61", :controller=>"v1/devices", :format=>:json}
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/rails-controller-testing-1.0.2/lib/rails/controller/testing/template_assertions.rb:61:in `process'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/devise-4.3.0/lib/devise/test/controller_helpers.rb:33:in `block in process'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/devise-4.3.0/lib/devise/test/controller_helpers.rb:100:in `catch'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/devise-4.3.0/lib/devise/test/controller_helpers.rb:100:in `_catch_warden'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/devise-4.3.0/lib/devise/test/controller_helpers.rb:33:in `process'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/rails-controller-testing-1.0.2/lib/rails/controller/testing/integration.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Integration>'
     # ./spec/controllers/v1/devices_controller_spec.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you try instead with a `request` type spec `type: :request`?.

Comment: Well, different error now: `unknown keyword: format`

Comment: Tweaking a little more, got rid of `format: :json`.  Now getting: `Failure/Error: expect(response.status).to be(200)
     
       expected #<Integer:401> => 200
            got #<Integer:605> => 302
     
       Compared using equal?, which compares object identity,
       but expected and actual are not the same object. Use
       `expect(actual).to eq(expected)` if you don't care about
       object identity in this example.`

Comment: Which Rails version are you using?

Comment: Rails 5.  Incidentally, do I use `request` specs for PUT/PATCH as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another solution to not change `type` into `request`. This error shows because of adding `serial_number` parameter in `show` devise route, you can add `serial_number` in your `get` url.

```
RSpec.describe V1::DevicesController, type: :controller do

  it "shows device info" do
    device = FactoryGirl.create(:device)
    get :show, params: { serial_number: device.serial_number }, :format => :json
    expect(response.status).to be(200)
  end
end
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: That still yields `No route matches {:action=>"/v1/devices/0dea0ba7746c42d49c869ea7a9639144", :controller=>"v1/devices", :format=>:json}`

Comment: Thanks. I have run this in my project also getting same error. You can change to this `get :show, params: { serial_number: device.serial_number }, :format => :json`.

Comment: Yup, that worked and I didn't have to change from `type: :controller`

Answer (score -1):

Alright, starting with @sebastián's comment, I changed the spec to:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe V1::DevicesController, type: :request do

  it "shows device info" do
    headers = {
      "ACCEPT" => "application/json",     # This is what Rails 4 accepts
    }

    device = FactoryGirl.create(:device)
    get v1_device_path(device.serial_number), :headers => headers
    expect(response.content_type).to eq("application/json")
  end
end
```

And my test passes now.

Comment: You could likely do `get v1_device_path(device_serial_number, format: :json)` too.

Comment: @RyanBigg that changes the error string a little, but still `no route matches`..... `No route matches {:action=>"/v1/devices/ae04a224c8724a609dacb0567afd643f.json", :controller=>"v1/devices"}`